# How to get patchset "Author" out of Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

When using "[gerrit query](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.2.1/cmd-query.html)" with the option "--patch-sets" the output includes the patchset "committer" (called "uploader"). But the patchset "author" is not included in the output.

Query:

```
ssh gerrit gerrit query --format=JSON --patch-sets --all-approvals -- status:merged project:demo-project-2 -age:1week
```

As "committer" and "author" can be different (as "forge author" has been enabled) I need to know also the "author" in order to create a metric which reveals if anyone reviewed their own code (giving their own commit code-review +2).

According to [Shawn](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/repo-discuss/author/repo-discuss/CVegBAlkQag/kjH8Ai9AgQ4J) it is not possible to get patchset "author" using "gerrit query".

So, question is, is it possible to get patchset "author" in another way? It must be stored in Gerrit somewhere, right, but where?

Comment: One note: The "uploader" retrieved using "gerrit query" is not the commit "committer". So using "gerrit query" gives you neither "author" nor "committer" of the commit. You have to go directly to the git repo for this (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way to do it is to ssh into the server:

ssh user@gerrit git --git-dir=/home/gerrit2/review_site/git/Project.git/ rev-list --pretty=\"format:Author Name:%an Author Email:%ae\" refs/changes/02/2/1

Comment: This could work. However you need to add <number> to the rev-list cmd and set that to 1, otherwise it returns all commits reachable from the given link/commit.

Comment: Also you need to place the "" differently. This works: git --git-dir=/home/user/etc/gerrit/git/project.git/ rev-list -1 --pretty=format:"Author:%an%nEmail:%ae" refs/changes/75/375/1

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Gerrit it's possible to include the author and committer of patch sets in the results returned by the REST API query.

For example:

```
curl -n --digest "https://review.example.com/a/changes/?q=owner:self&o=CURRENT_REVISION&o=CURRENT_COMMIT"
```

will fetch all changes owned by the current user.  The results will include the patch sets as [RevisionInfo entity](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#revision-info) with the committer and author included in the [CommitInfo entity](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#commit-info).

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to my question is: Use [REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html) instead of [Gerrit Query](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5.2/cmd-query.html).

It seems that Gerrit is moving away from "Gerrit Query" and instead focuses more on "REST API".